# importing network in Statnet in R

Tags: r, matrix, statnet

I am new to STATNET and know nothing about it. I have a data set which has 3 columns. The first and second column contain nodes whereas the third contains edge value. How should I import this to STATNET? I suspect I need to convert this dataset to a matrix. How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 2):

No need to change it into a matrix, you can use a weighted edgelist right away. Try something like

```
library(statnet)

dat <- structure(
    list(a = c(1, 2, 4), b = c(2, 3, 5), c = c(10, 1, 1)),
    .Names    = c("a", "b", "c"),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L),
    class     = "data.frame"
)


g <- as.network(
    dat,
    ignore.eval = FALSE,
    names.eval  = 'weight',
    matrix.type = 'edgelist',
    directed    = FALSE
    )
```

Comment: thanks. How can I draw the network? do you know any good resource for learning statnet?

Comment: You can use something like `plot.network(g,edge.lwd = get.edge.value(g,"weight"))`. I don't know a comprehensive tutorial for `statnet` but you could also look into the `igraph` library which is quite popular and has tons of documentation. Finally consider accepting the answer if it helped you

Comment: do you want me to help you to plot?